# How to fix Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error

Tags: wordpress, azure, subdomain, domain-name

I'm currently running a wordpress site and i'm getting the following error when i switch to my subdomain:

**Access to font at 'https://www.site.fr/wp-content/themes/Divi/core/admin/fonts/modules.ttf' from origin 'https://blog.site.fr' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Because of this i get a bug and some of the icons in the page are no longer displaying because of the file above that cannot be loaded.

Has anyone got an idea about how to fix this bug?

Thank you

Comment: When you switch to your sub-domain do you update the site url and wordpress address via the backend or `wp-config.php` as well?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't have the subdomain url in wp-config or the backend. I just have it set in my DNS records and i use a redirection plugin to redirect all posts like: https://www.site.fr/article1 => https://blog.site.fr/article1 which works and everything loads fine except for that one file "modules.ttf"